# How to get the size of a song in ipod library?

Tags: ios, xamarin, mpmediaquery, mpmediaplayercontroller, mpmedialibrary

I have been working on a media player app.I am able to get the media items by using the media query,group them based on different groupings and add various filters to narrow down my search.

Now my requirement is to find out the size of a particular song in the iPod library.I tried google but did not get the direction to proceed.Is it possible to get the song size or is it not supported by the apis. BTW I am using Xamarin for developing the app.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "size"?

Comment: Well when I say size,I mean the physical size of the song(eg 4mb etc) in ipad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get the size of the song.

```
NSURL *urlAsset = [anItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
AVURLAsset *songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:urlAsset options:nil];
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset: songAsset presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
CMTime half = CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(exportSession.asset.duration, 1); exportSession.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, half);
long long size = exportSession.estimatedOutputFileLength;
NSLog(@"size=%lld",size);
```